# How do I allow full brightness control on Unity?

Tags: unity

When I use the brightness changing buttons Unity changes the brightness by two levels each time to create a nice effect.  However, I only have about 10 different brightness settings and so this effect has caused a reduction in brightness settings to 5.  I change my brightness regularly to suit the lighting in the room I'm in, but am unable to do this so effectively now that the number of levels has been reduced.

Is there any way of turning off this brightness effect and controlling my brightness setting more sensitively?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: It may not be 2 levels it changes at a time but 3, I've worked this out as the brightness control panel allows you to set the brightness accurately and there seem to be a couple of settings that the button misses completely when I change the brightness with the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a brightness indicator applet to change the brighness:

[image]

It can be downloaded from [here](http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128). It works with 11.04 and 11.10 and is said to work with 12.04.

---

**Update:** You can try this but this will change your brightness hot keys:

**1.** Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and `xbacklight`.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager xbacklight
```

**2.** Run it and go to commands. Do as shown:

[image]

**3.** Add key bindings:

[image]

**4.** You should be now able to increase brightness using F7 key and decrease using F6 key.

**Note:** Do not play with CCSM, if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, this seems like a good solution for now but I really would like to get the buttons to just work properly.

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Does this method understand brightness keys on my keyboard, or do I have to change what my function keys do?

Comment: The F6 and F7 keys will also change the brightness.

Comment: It's just that F6 and F7 are used for other things, unfortunately it seems that this method won't work if I can't assign my brightness keys.

Comment: If you don't want to assign those keys, you can use any other combination with Ctrl, Alt, and Shift.